ImageMagick don't run with php exec()
I tried to use ImageMagick to convert images with php. The ImageMagick run on cli using the exec() command, but it dont work. I already tried to run ImageMagick with the same command on linux terminal and it works fine. I know that ImageMagick have a php extension named Imagick, but the ideia is use the ImageMagick cli command when Imagick is not avaible.
Command:
<?php exec("/opt/lampp/htdocs/website/sistema/application/libraries/binary/./magick /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/assets/images/backgroundb.png -quality 100 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/assets/images/backgroundb.webp"); ?>

Tried to run ImageMagick cli command with php exec() when Imagick is not avaible.

Most likely the user that PHP is running under does not have access to that path. You should inspect the output of the command. Also, the provided code is syntactically invalid, it is missing quotes. Make sure to always post your code exactly as you are using.

"Tried to run ImageMagick cli command with php exec() when Imagick is not avaible" - do you imagine this scenario happening? Couldn't you just install the extension?

I can't install the extension, they need run cli. I add they quites and still not working. The Path and the ImageMagick has 777 permission, and i already use the Google cwebp in the same Path and It Works Fine.

I am very unclear on most parts of that comment.

What is the /./ in the executable path for?  And if you're having trouble, why not remove it immediately to see if that's the problem?

exec() has optional arguments to get the command output and exit code, and it also returns the last line of successful output or false on error. Use that to figure out what's wrong. You may also want to redirect stderr to stdout so you don't miss anything.
